# package csquote edit enquote to get single quote

Tags: punctuation, csquotes

I am using the package `csquotes`:

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
```

When I'm using `\enquote{my text here}`, I get double quote. How can I get singlequote instead by using  `\enquote{}` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`csquotes` has predefined styles based on the language setting. If your language is `british`, then you get single quotes. Otherwise you could define them manually. You can alter them using `\DeclareQuoteStyle` as described in the manual on pp. 14--15 (`texdoc csquotes`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
He said, \enquote{This is a quote that references \enquote{another quote}}.
\end{document}
```

[image]